# Increment expression for 'for' doesn't have any effect

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-warnings

I have a class, Square:

```
class Square
{
   typedef enum {kTop = 0x80, kRight = 0x40, kBottom = 0x20, kLeft = 0x10} Side;
   // Other functions and stuff
}
```

In one of my functions, I have a `for` loop that performs an operation involving each of the sides of a `Square`. I made it like this:

```
for (Square::Side side = Square::kLeft; side < Square::kLeft; side << 1) // Warning here
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

First, the loop would work on the left side, and then it would shift the side one position to the left, making the side equal to the bottom side. After the `for` loop has performed its operations on the Top side, it would shift left again, pushing the bit off of the number and making it equal to 0, which is less than kLeft, and the loop would end.

However, it's giving me a warning that says "**for increment expression has no effect**". Does this mean that my shift operation is not happening?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, because the stop condition is false on the first attempt:

```
Square::Side side = Square::kLeft
```

renders

```
side < Square::kLeft;
```

false.

Perhaps you meant `side <= Square::kTop` or similar and `side <<= 1`.

Comment: I was still getting the warning after I changed `side < Square::kLeft` to `side == 0`, but this definitely would have caused problems for me int he future, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're not assigning the value of the shift back to side.  Try this:

> (Square::Side side = Square::kLeft; side < Square::kLeft; side = side << 1)

or `side <<= 1`.

You'll also need to fix your terminating condition:

> side <= Square.kTop

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot to do that

Comment: I think Luchian beat me to it across the board.